# Plotting a family of contour plots

Tags: plotting

How can I plot the following equation with $k$ assumed to be an integer"?
I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
ContourPlot[{Element[k,Integers], Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] == 4 + k*Pi},{x, -17, 17}, {y, -17, 17}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3871/5

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like what you want:

```
ContourPlot[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -17, 17}, {y, -17, 17}, 
 Contours -> Table[4 + k*Pi, {k, -10, 10}]]
```

which produces

[image]

or perhaps you want the image to be styled like this

[image]

which is obtained by adding the option `ContourShading -> None`.

Comment: Don't working....

Comment: Can you be more specific... *what* isn't working. Is this not the sort of picture you want? Does your copy of Mathematica not recognize these commands?

Comment: not, there's not output. and these is the free trial.

Comment: Or alternately: `ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] == 4 + k*Pi, {k, -10, 10}], {x, -17, 
  17}, {y, -17, 17}]`

Comment: Doesn't working...